# Pandas insert percent difference from one column to the next

Tags: pandas

As an example, how to get from

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
```

to

```
    a   a->b     b   b->c  c    c->a
0   1   200%     2   150%  3    33%
1   4   125%     5   120%  6    66%
```

I tried something like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3) + 1, columns=list("abc"))
for c1, c2 in [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]:
    df[f"{c1}/{c2}"] = 100 * df.iloc[:, c1] / df.iloc[:, c2]
```

together with reordering columns (since this appends all new columns at the end) but it's super unreadable and looks like a Pandas antipattern.

**Update**

I should mention it's not okay to rely on a pattern in the column names as there isn't one, i.e. they're not numbered/alphabetical/etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can do with `numpy` `roll`

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.values/np.roll(df.values, -1, axis=1),
                          columns=df.columns + '/' + np.roll(df.columns,-1), 
                          index=df.index))
Out[83]: 
   a  b  c  a/b       b/c  c/a
0  1  2  3  0.5  0.666667  3.0
1  4  5  6  0.8  0.833333  1.5
```